# Convert a vector in R to a nested list

Tags: r, nested-lists

I have a vector of length n and I want to convert it to a nested list. The outer list should be of length `n / 2` and each item in this list should have two sub-lists. The first sub-list in each list will hold an odd numbered element from the vector and the second sub-list will hold an even numbered element (see my example code if this isn't making sense... I'm having a hard time describing it in general terms).

**Question:** *Is there a way to convert this vector into a nested list without using for loops?*
I'm doing this in the context of a simulation and so I want to make sure it is as fast as possible. The aforementioned vector will vary in length between iterations of the simulation, so I'm trying to find an answer I can generalize to a vector of length n. The vector will always be even though.

Example vector and list:

`ex_vector <- 1:6
ex_list <- list(
  list(1, 2),
  list(3, 4),
  list(5, 6)
)`

Edit: fixed an error in my example code

Comment: 'nested list' and 'as fast as possible' are not really consistent. Create a matrix `matrix(ex_vector, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)` or perhaps data.frame with indexes `data.frame(ex_vector, i = rep(seq_len(length(ex_vector) / 2), each = 2), j = 1:2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand the general principle, but the code below works for the example:

```
> x <- apply(matrix(ex_vector, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE), 1, as.list)
> str(x)
List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : int 1
  ..$ : int 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : int 3
  ..$ : int 4
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : int 5
  ..$ : int 6
```

Comment: `split(ex_vector,col(matrix(ex_vector,2)))`

Answer (score 1):

We create a grouping variable with `gl` and `split`the `vector` into a `list` and convert to `list` with `as.list`

```
n <- 2
out <- lapply(split(ex_vector, as.integer(gl(length(ex_vector), n,
                 length(ex_vector)))), as.list)
str(out)
#List of 3
# $ 1:List of 2
#  ..$ : int 1
#  ..$ : int 2
# $ 2:List of 2
#  ..$ : int 3
#  ..$ : int 4
# $ 3:List of 2
#  ..$ : int 5
#  ..$ : int 6
```

Or use `%/%` to `split`

```
lapply(split(ex_vector, (seq_along(ex_vector)-1) %/% n + 1), as.list)
```

---

Or compactly

```
split(as.list(ex_vector), cumsum(seq_along(ex_vector) %%2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n <- length(ex_vector)
lapply(split(ex_vector, rep(1:(n/2), each = 2)), split, 1:2)
```